# Python multiprocessing a child function

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have trying to learn multi processing.
I have a simple function which generates a list of numbers and I am trying to use multiprocessing to add the numbers if it is divisible by 10.

My objective is to run the child function in parallel with available cpu.

```
import  multiprocessing
import time

def add_multiple_of_10_v0(number):
    number_list = []
    for i in range(1, number):
        x = i**3 + i**2 + i + 1
        number_list.append(x)
    print(number_list)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    result = 0
    for value in pool.map(check_multiple_10_v0, number_list):
        if value > 0:
            result = result + value
        else:
            pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

def check_multiple_10_v0(in_number):
    if in_number % 10 == 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        return in_number
    else:
        return -1
```

I am getting the below error -
RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Am new to python and multiprocessing and would appreciate guidance.

Comment: error message seems pretty clear on what you need to do, how are you callin g `add_multiple...` function?

Comment: I am calling it from a separate file through import

Comment: show the code of how you are calling it

Comment: From a separate file - from multiple import add_multiple_of_10_v0

result = add_multiple_of_10_v0(in_number)

Comment: put the `result =...` under the `if __name__...` block like shown in the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247644/discussion-between-prem-ji-and-charchit).